# Including extra libraries on the link line

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll, linker

When linking an executable, if it does not make reference to any of the symbols in one of the DLLs on the link line, will it still depend on that DLL at runtime?

To make the question concrete, suppose I am building an application from Visual Studio project `foo`.

Under Project Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies I have specified `bar.lib`, the import library for `bar.dll`, even though it is not required to link `foo.exe` successfully.

Do I still need to distribute `bar.dll` with my application since I have marked it as a linking dependency?

Comment: If the linker is doing it's job properly then it should ignore the unreferenced dll. There's an easy way to test this, create such a project and then see if it runs if you remove `bar.dll`.

Comment: Or use dependency walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if you application lists the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not required.

A import library only a library and the EXE will include only the references to functions which are used. By the way to verify this you can use DUMPBIN.EXE utility or dependencies walker (see http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which are part of Visual Studio packages. Just type `DUMPBIN.EXE foo.exe /imports` or open foo.exe with the dependencies walker.